# How do I get this SQL to return a 1 if no rows are found

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL Server 2008

```
SELECT ('ABC-' + 
    MAX(CAST(
        (SUBSTRING([ID], CASE CHARINDEX('-', [ID])
            WHEN 0
                THEN LEN([ID]) + 1            
            ELSE CHARINDEX('-', [ID]) + 1
            END, 1000)+1)
            AS VARCHAR)
            )) AS next_id      
  FROM [STUFF]
  WHERE [FK_DATA] = '12345'
```

Table `[STUFF]` contains column `[ID]` with values like "ABC-1", "ABC-2". But the WHERE clause may result in 0 rows returned.

The query gets the next increment of the ABS's, e.g. "ABC-3". Except when there are no matching rows. Then I don't get any results.

It's part of a sub-query, so I need it to return 'ABC-1' instead of nothing. I.e. the inner part has to return a 1. (My outer query then inserts this newest increment.)

Comment: It may help to post the whole query if possible. This would help to see if this query is part of the select statement or part of a join etc.

Comment: You might want to consider storing the separate *components* of your `ID`s in separate column(s) and then only combining them into the string-with-dash-separators as a computed column. That would allow you to work with the component parts without having to do all of this string manipulation.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I fully agree. This ID field is actually free-form, and I'm using them in this way just as a proof of concept without modifying the current structure. Once I demonstrate this works I will hopefully be able to `normalize` this a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT ('ABC-' + 
    ISNULL(
      MAX(CAST(
          (SUBSTRING([ID], CASE CHARINDEX('-', [ID])
              WHEN 0
                  THEN LEN([ID]) + 1            
              ELSE CHARINDEX('-', [ID]) + 1
              END, 1000)+1)
              AS VARCHAR)
              )) AS next_id 
    , 1) 
  FROM [STUFF]
  WHERE [FK_DATA] = '12345'
```

The sub-query is placed inside an ISNULL function. By doing this, you are saying that if the sub-query returns a value of NULL, replace it with a value of 1.

If rows are returned, the result will be as you already have it, but if no rows are returned, the result will be 1.

Comment: ISNULL works only if the result returns NULL value. In this case no rows are returned so the result will be the same I guess. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Nisha no rows is same as `NULL` I thought. And then I tried something like this and it didn't work. No rows returned. But now, I try this, and it does work! I must have made a mistake before.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this, depending on the context, although it's not too elegant

```
SELECT TOP 1 next_id
FROM (
    SELECT 'ABC-' + 
        MAX(CAST(
        (SUBSTRING([ID], CASE CHARINDEX('-', [ID])
            WHEN 0
                THEN LEN([ID]) + 1            
            ELSE CHARINDEX('-', [ID]) + 1
            END, 1000)+1)
            AS VARCHAR)
            ) AS next_id
    FROM [STUFF]
    WHERE [FK_DATA] = '12345'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ABC-1' AS next_id
) AS next_id
```

Comment: That looks possible. I don't care about elegance. I would try this immediately but now my local windows machine has crashed haha

Answer (score 0):

Use this `@temptable` in your subquery or anywhere

```
declare @temptable as table (next_id int)
    insert into @temptable
    SELECT ('ABC-' + 
        MAX(CAST(
            (SUBSTRING([ID], CASE CHARINDEX('-', [ID])
                WHEN 0
                    THEN LEN([ID]) + 1            
                ELSE CHARINDEX('-', [ID]) + 1
                END, 1000)+1)
                AS VARCHAR)
                )) AS next_id      
      FROM [STUFF]
      WHERE [FK_DATA] = '12345'

    if not exists (select next_id from @temptable)
    select 'ABC-1' as next_id 
    else 
    select * from @temptable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'ABC-' + CAST(
ISNULL((
    SELECT MAX(SUBSTRING([ID], CASE CHARINDEX('-', [ID])
            WHEN 0
                THEN LEN([ID]) + 1            
            ELSE CHARINDEX('-', [ID]) + 1
            END, 1000)
            )   
    FROM [STUFF]
    WHERE [FK_DATA] = '123456'
    ), 0) + 1 as VARCHAR(10)) AS next_id
```